# Cookies don't get attached even after using storage API

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari, webkit, storage-access-api

```
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.sandbox.add('allow-scripts', 'allow-storage-access-by-user-activation', 'allow-same-origin');
iframe.onload = function () {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
        document.getElementById('test-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
            getStorageAccess().then(_ => {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', 'https://example.net/v1/set-key-authorization-cookie/cb325a10-9404-4f77-b615-319415fa945a', true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                xhr.send('{"KeyAuthorizationToken": "eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ij"}');
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED && this.status == 200) {
                        var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr2.open('GET', 'https://example.net/v1/get-key/cb325a10-9404-4f77-b615-319415fa945a?encrypted-key-container=eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1Ni', true);
                        xhr2.withCredentials = true;
                        xhr2.send(null);
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log("The iframe is loaded" + getStorageAccess());
        });
    });
};
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

My inner request xhr2 needs some cookies from xhr request. `getStorageAccess` promise is resolved but no cookies in request.

Comment: how is the iframe onload triggered? I really hope those keys you posted aren't supposed to be private!!! they aren't any more!!!!

Comment: to be honest, I can't see why you're even using an iframe - none of what you've posted is using the iframe, so what's the iframe even for?

Comment: onload is triggered when iframe is appended in document. Storage API works only from iframe, so was trying to execute fetch token (first xhr request) from an iframe's load function. @Bravo

Comment: *onload is triggered when iframe is appended in document* I know that, your code didn't show that - however, all the code you are running is running in the main document, none of it is running in the context of the empty iframe you just created - i.e. `iframe.onload = function () { all this runs in the parent of the iframe, not the iframe }` .... *Storage API works only from iframe* you mean storage access API

Comment: by the way, storage-access-API mentions `requestStorageAccess` and `hasStorageAccess` - it's interesting that you never use either of those methods

Comment: ```function getStorageAccess() {
    if (!document || !document.hasStorageAccess) {
        this.logger.debug(`No storage access on userAgent:${navigator.userAgent}`);
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return document.hasStorageAccess().then(hasAccess => {
        if (!hasAccess) {
            return document.requestStorageAccess();
        }
        return Promise.resolve();
    });
}```

Comment: sorry @Bravo, I forgot to share helper method. I am new to writing code in javascript. could you help on modifying the script such that it executes from an iframe and not the parent.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with that - I have no idea what your end goal is - like, what domain are you trying to get cookies from (or send them to, I seriously have no idea what your code is for)

Comment: I understand. but my use case is simple. from webpage `abc.com`, i am issuing a `POST` request to `example.net/set-auth-cookie`. and then i get set-cookie in response header. and this cookie is supposed to be attached in subsequent `GET` request to same domain `example.net/get-key` for authorizing the user.

Comment: `i am issuing a POST request` ... well, that's what you want to do, but you're not actually doing it, since none of the code is actually running in the iframe ... also, you can not get cookies for `example.net` unless the domain of the iframe IS `example.net` ... which it isn't

Comment: ok could you share any pseudo code or link that i can read and understand. like how to run code in iframe and fix the domain of iframe